# How do you test exceptions using mockito in RCP Application?

Tags: junit, mockito, swt, rcp

I have the following code in my `performFinish()` method of my Wizard Class :

```
public boolean performFinish() {

    try {
      getContainer().run(true, false, changeArtifactRunnable());
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
      LoggerClass.logException(e);
    }
```

I want to test Exception for `InvocationTargetException` and  `InterruptedException` using Mockito.
In the above code, `getContainer()` method is from `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard` class and

```
public void run(boolean fork, boolean cancelable,
            IRunnableWithProgress runnable) throws InvocationTargetException,
            InterruptedException;
```

method is from `org.eclipse.jface.operation.IRunnableContext` class.

How do I test both the exceptions in `performFinish()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **expected** keyword in order to do so. For example:

```
@Test(expected = InvocationTargetException.class)
public void testInvocationTargetException()    {
    \\Invoke the method to be tested under the conditions, such that InvocationTargetException is thrown by it. No need of any assert statements
}
```

===========================================================================
Edit:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class EditArtifactWizardTest    {
        @Spy 
        //use correct constructor of EditArtifactWizard 
        private EditArtifactWizard editArtifactWizardSpy=Mockito.spy(new EditArtifactWizard ());
           @Test(expected = InvocationTargetException.class)
        public void testInvocationTargetException()    {
            \\Invoke the method to be tested under the conditions, such that InvocationTargetException is thrown by it. No need of any assert statements
            Mockito.when(editArtifactWizardSpy.getContainer()).thenThrow(InvocationTargetException.class);
            editArtifactWizardSpy.performFinish();
        }
    }
```

You can create the Spy of EditArtifactWizard class and mock the behavior of the getContainerMethod.

P.S: Please excuse for typos or compilation error as I am not using any editor.

Comment: Can you please let me how to test for the above scenario because in my code, run() method is throwing the exception which is present in performFinish() mehod.

Comment: Can you share the entire class conatining method performFinish

Comment: Edited my answer, see if it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help. getContainer() is calling run() method. run() method is inturn throwing the Exceptions but not getContainer() method. Can you please help how do I invoke run() method.

Comment: In that case,go through the documentation of Wizard class and see the relationship between  IRunnableContext and Wizard class and mock the behavior of run method accordingly.